# Infinite Loop when passing Redux State to React Component

Tags: reactjs, redux

**[EDIT]**

The problem was not the isAuth property but the props.location in the Redirect Component in ProtectedRoute ! Nonetheless, if you have a problem to understand useSelector or mapStateToProps, go to the @Versifiction's anwsers !

**[END EDIT]**

I have a React/Redux app with a isAuth property inside a authReducer. I want to pass it to my ProtectedRoute Component in order to check the behaviour.

I have this error and i'm sure it's related to passing isAuth to ProtectedComponent :

> **Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded**

My AppContainer

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import history from "./constants/history";
import * as ROUTES from './constants/routes';
import ProtectedRoute from "@components/HOC/ProtectedRoute";

import LandingPage from "../domains/Main/LandingPage";
import AdminLandingPage from '@domains/Admin/AdminLandingPage';
import SessionLandingPage from '@domains/Session/SessionLandingPage';
import SignInPage from "../domains/Auth/SignInPage/SignInPage";
import SignUpPage from "../domains/Auth/SignUpPage/SignUpPage";
import PasswordForgetPage from "../domains/Auth/PasswordForgetPage/PasswordForgetPage";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'


function AppContainer() {

    const [checkAuth, setCheckAuth] = useState(false);
    const { isAuth } = useSelector(state => state.authReducer);



    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <ProtectedRoute exact  path={ROUTES.MAIN_LANDING} component={LandingPage}/>
            <Route exact path={ROUTES.SIGN_IN} component={SignInPage}/>
            <ProtectedRoute exact path={ROUTES.ADMIN_LANDING} component={AdminLandingPage}/>
            <ProtectedRoute exact path={ROUTES.SESSION_LANDING} component={SessionLandingPage}/>
        </Router>
    );
}


export default AppContainer;
```

The Console.log show the value "False" as intented.

Just by use Selector, i have the infinite loop error.

The State of the AuthReducer :

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    loading: false,
    error: '',
    isAuth : false
};
```

My ProtectedRoute Component

```
const ProtectedRoute = (
    {
        component: Component,
        isAuth,
        ...rest
    }
) => {
    if(isAuth === null) {
        return 'loading...'
    }
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => {
                return isAuth
                    ?
                    (<Component {...rest} {...props} />) :
                    (<Redirect to={{pathname: '/', state: {from: props.location}}}/>)
            }}
        />

    )
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use mapStateToProps to send datas from the store to the props of a component, you have to import the connect method from the react-redux package first,

Then in the mapStateToProps function, you put as property the name of the data in the props (isAuth), and as a value the location in the global store (state.authReducer.isAuth)

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function AppContainer(props) {
    const { isAuth } = props;
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <ProtectedRoute exact isAuth={isAuth} path={ROUTES.MAIN_LANDING} component={LandingPage}/>
            <Route exact path={ROUTES.SIGN_IN} component={SignInPage}/>
            <ProtectedRoute exact isAuth={true} path={ROUTES.ADMIN_LANDING} component={AdminLandingPage}/>
            <ProtectedRoute exact isAuth={true} path={ROUTES.SESSION_LANDING} component={SessionLandingPage}/>
        </Router>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuth: state.authReducer.isAuth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AppContainer);
```

Comment: This is the same issue in fine. If i try in the AppContainer  


   `const { isAuth } = useSelector(state => state.authReducer);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCheckAuth(isAuth);
    }, []);`  


I have the infinite Loop either. I don't understand where the problem is. :/

Comment: can I see the whole component somewhere ?

Comment: I recommend you to use the mapStateToProps function from react-redux https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate to send state data to the props of your component, I'll edit my example in that sense

Comment: Unfortunatly, same result... 

The issue seems to appear when i try to pass the isAuth in the ProtectedRoute. If I only console.log the isAuth, there is no problem.

Comment: so in the ProtectedRoute component, you are 100% sure that you get the isAuth value ?

Comment: Seems the problem was .... the props.location in the <Redirect> and not the isAuth. This stuff made me crazy ! 

Thanks you for the explanation about using this selectors from Redux. It was useful nonetheless !

Comment: sorry for not helping you more, it's hard for me when I don't have the project running under my eyes :(